# Does nohup command work when run in Cygwin(Windows server)?

Tags: windows, unix, cygwin, nohup

I am trying to run a unix script in windows. It takes 3 days to do its job. Somebody has to monitor the machine while running the script. Is `nohup` command possible in Windows or give me any alternative approach.Peace!

Used `nohup script.sh &`

Answer (score 0):

Well, cygwin has a nohup command, so I presume it will work as advertised.

Alternatively in DOS shell you can use the START command.

For example:

```
C:\> START c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe myscript.sh
```

See here:
[How to detach "git gui" started in "Git bash" on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763615/how-to-detach-git-gui-started-in-git-bash-on-windows/20843432#20843432)

Comment: I just want to confirm one thing will this work even when i close my windows server.Also how do i kill the process.

Comment: I have tried nohup in cygwin for windows server,it didn't work.It stops when session closes.Can you suggest me something else that worls.

Comment: I'm far from an expert in this, but if all else fails, you might have to set it up as a windows service. Alternatively, cygwin has a unix style cron daemon, which you could use to run stuff in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to use nohup with cygwin, opening a hidden console (with the command run)  to launch emacs-X11

```
    nohup /bin/run /bin/emacs-X11 --display :0 &
```

In your case, it could be `nohup /bin/run script.sh &`